# How to call sub onchange of a dropdownlist while using AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, ajax.net

So, I know how to call a method onclick of a button using ajax, but I'd like to do the same when a user selects something new on a dropdownlist. I'll show code for what I've tried below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlHelloWorld" runat="server">

      <ContentTemplate>

        <div style="height: auto; overflow: auto; max-height:750px; width:100%;">
          <asp:DropDownList ID="mydropdownlist" runat="server" Enabled="true" OnChange="changeMyTable"></asp:DropDownList>   
          <asp:Table ID="mytable" runat="server"></asp:Table>
        </div>

      </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the page's aspx.vb:

```
Private Sub changeMyTable()
'Add rows to table
end sub
```

The problem is that "changeMyTable" is undefined when i change the dropdownlist.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure there is `OnChange` server event for Dropdownlist ?

Comment: I was using it to call some JS code, so I'm pretty sure. Now I'm just trying to use AJAX.

Comment: Thats what I am saying if you want to call the server side method from the javascript then you should make that method static. And post your js code too .

Comment: I see what you're saying now; there must be an event for OnChange in order to do it this way. This satisfies my question, so feel free to post an answer. I'm also not sure how to call a static server side method through JS, would you mind providing a quick example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `OnChange` event to call the code behind method from javascript. To access the code behind method you need to convert that method to the `WebMethod`. For that below is something you can try (Just an example)

```
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript code -

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function greet(txtN, txtLastN, txtMsg){
     var ctrlN = document.getElementById(txtN);
     var ctrlLastN = document.getElementById(txtLastN);
     var fullName = ctrlN.value + '  ' + ctrlLastN.value;
     PageMethods.greetUser(fullName, greetSuccess, greetFailed, txtMsg);
   }
  function greetSuccess(res, txtMsg) {
    var ctrlTxtMsg = document.getElementById(txtMsg);
    ctrlTxtMsg.value = res;
   }
  function greetFailed(res, dst) {
    alert(res.get_message());
   }
 </script>
```

Code behind method -

```
   <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
      Public Shared Function greetUser(ByVal fullName As String) As String
         Return "Welcome " & fullName & "!"
     End Function
```

Now you can call your javascript function `greet` from wherever you want and it will trigger the code behind method `greetUser`. More on this [is available here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180355/Calling-a-code-behind-function-from-JavaScript).

Comment: Fantastic answer, taught me much more than I hoped for.